# Searching in nested folder

Tags: files-and-directories

I'll start with an example, as it's easier to explain what I need.

Say for example I've a Project folder called "MainFolder".
In this folder there are a number of subfolders and nested subfolders.
One of these folders is called e.g. "Data", and there is one file in it called "data1.m"
In another folder (say "Script") there is a notebook ("script.nb") that imports the file "data1.m".

I'd like to write a code that will be part of the notebook "script.nb" that finds and imports the file "data1.m" wherever the folder Script and Data are.

This is because I may want to move the subfolders Script and Data in other folders without having to change the code.

The assumptions are:
- the folder name "MainFolder" is fixed
- all the project folders are in "MainFolder"
- the folder name "Data"is fixed
- the file name "data1.m" is fixed
- there may be other "data1.m" files in other subfolders of the project, but in such a case the subfolders won't be called "Data"
- the code must work on different machines with different OSs (Windows, macOS and Linux)

Here an example scheme of the folder structure, where I want to access "data1.m" wherever it is.

> MainFolder
>
> > subfolder_1
> >
> > subfolder_2
> >
> > > Data
> > >
> > > > data1.m
> >
> > subfolder_3
> >
> > > subsubfolder_1
> > >
> > > > Script
> > > >
> > > > > script.nb
> >
> > ...
> >
> > subfolder_n

I do have an idea of how to do that, but it seems to me that it is quite un-elegant and a bit verbose. I'll share that anyway despite the fact I don't think it's the best way of doing it:

```
 Select[
  FileNames["Data",
   FileNameJoin@#[[;; Position[#, "MainFolder"][[-1, 1]]]] &@
    FileNameSplit[NotebookDirectory[]],
   Infinity],
  DirectoryQ][[1]]
```

Comment: Does your current code achieve what you want? If it does, what would you like to improve *specifically*? Speed, robustness (in which case we need a case where it fails)... Otherwise this reads like a "make my code pretty" question. I don't necessarily oppose that, but in this case this is such a niche application that any effort would probably only apply to your particular problem.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, you are right. At the beginning I didn't have a proper code for that, so I wrote the question (I just had a piece of code that didn't work properly in all the cases). Then I found the code I wrote (I could have actually written that as an answer, but at the end I just edited the post). However, I still think is not ideal, and I thought that there may be some built-in function that I ignore that can simplify the code.

Comment: For example, there may be some function that I'm not aware of that does the part of going back to the MainFolder easily (something like the bash command cd */ but backwards instead of forward). And I think if there is, this may be of interest to other users as well :)

Comment: Does MMA have a built in function for selecting the elements of a list from [[1]] to a given entry?
e.g. list={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} ;

function[list,e]={a,b,c,d,e}

Comment: Not a built in that I can think of. You could use: `list /. {a___, e, ___} :> {a, e}`. However, what should happen if the element is duplicated in the list? Are the elements strings or symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following:

```
With[
 {positionofMain = NestWhile[
    ParentDirectory,
    NotebookDirectory[],
    Not@*StringEndsQ["MainFolder"],
    1(*supply back only one result*), 100(*safety stop*)
    ]},
 First@
   FileNames[
     __ ~~ FileNameJoin[{"Data", "data1.m"}],
     positionofMain, Infinity
   ]
]
```

The `NestWhile` traverses the directory tree upwards towards its root until it finds `MainFolder`. This gives us a fully qualified path to that folder. We then drill down from there using `FileNames` looking for files that contain `Data\data1.m` in their path. The use of OS-independent built-ins like `FileNameJoin` to introduce the OS-appropriate filename separator should make this reasonably portable across operating systems.

`FileNames` returns a list, but your problem indicated that the desired file/folder combination is unique, so we can blindly take the first element. That's the fully qualified path to the file you want to load.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the use of NestWhile for doing this.
It seems that the code you propose brakes if "Data" is a subfolder of MainFolder, while it runs smoothly when "Data" is a subsubfolder.
That can probably be fixed using BlankNullSequence ___ instead of BlankSequence __ :D

Comment: @Fraccalo Yep I think so too. Glad you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Combining what I proposed in the OP, @MarcoB's answer and a new idea I had (using SplitBy, that simplify my original code a bit):

```
With[{positionofMain = 
   FileNameJoin //@ 
    SplitBy[FileNameSplit[NotebookDirectory[]], # == "MainFolder" &][[
     1 ;; 2]]},
 First@FileNames[___ ~~ FileNameJoin[{"Data", "data1.m"}], 
   positionofMain, Infinity]]
```